# Fish commandline: get cursor position in current process

Tags: fish

With fish [commandline](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#commandline) command I can get current process part of commandline and current cursor position in entire buffer, but not in current process, e.g for commandline buffer

```
> echo test; echo $flounder
```

(with the cursor on the 'o' of 'flounder')

```
> commandline -
```

going to return

```
echo $flounder
```

and

```
> commandline -Cp
19
```

Could I somehow obtain cursor position in current process (8 for this example)?

```
> commandline -Cp
```

returns error.

UPD:
I think

```
> string length (commandline -cp)
```

would return exactly what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> string length (commandline -cp)
```

works fine